# c++ rehash on a LinkedList of pointers

Tags: c++, for-loop, linked-list, hashmap

I have a fully functioning hashMap class and everything seems to be working very well EXCEPT a rehash function designed to create a hashmap when the load factor of the previous hashmap reaches 0.8.

```
void HashMap::reHash()
{
    logins = 0;
    numberOfPairs = 0;
    Node** newBucket = new Node* [(2 * lengthOfMap) + 1];
    for(int i = 0; i < lengthOfMap; i++)
    {
        Node* oldHead = bucketList[i];
        for(Node* temp = oldHead; temp != nullptr; temp = temp-> next)
        {
            std::string key = oldHead->key;
            std::string value = oldHead->value;
            unsigned int index = hash(key) % lengthOfMap;
            if(newBucket[index] == nullptr)
            {
                std::cout << "HIT" << std::endl;
                newBucket[i] = new Node;
                newBucket[i]->key = key;
                newBucket[i]->value = value;
                newBucket[i]->next = nullptr;
                numberOfPairs[index]++;
                logins++;
            }

            else if (bucketList[index] != nullptr)
            {
                Node* temp = bucketList[index];
                while(temp->next != nullptr)
                {
                    temp = temp->next;
                }
                Node* n = new Node;
                n->key = key;
                n->value = value;
                temp->next = n;
                n->next = nullptr;
                std::cout << "FAIL at index: " << index << std::endl;
                //numberOfPairs[index]++;
                logins++;
            }   
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < lengthOfMap; ++i)
    {
        if( bucketList[i] )
        {
            Node* first = bucketList[i];
            while( first )
            {
                Node* temp = first->next;
                delete first;
                first = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    delete bucketList;
    bucketList = newBucket;
    lengthOfMap = (2 * lengthOfMap) + 1;
}
```

bucketList[] is my previous array full of Node* which each begin the first link in a linked list. I have added a couple std::cout for my own benefit, and I seem to be stuck in a permanent loop reading `FAIL at index:0` over and over again. I will admit I am new to the for loop iterating through the linked list, which I think is the source of my problem, but I'm looking for any helpful input.
Thanks again.

Comment: Side note: You can do this without having to reallocate any nodes if you're careful enough. You can literally move `Node`s from one bucket-list to another. It is a little tedious, but the performance benefit, especially for expensive object copies, is well worth it.

Comment: @WhozCraig How do you move the Nodes like that?

Comment: Actually I just reviewed this entire algorithm, and its a mess (sorry for the brutal truth, but its a fact). You're not using the right size for your new modulus, you're using the wrong index when inserting a new list head (`i` should be `index`), etc. You may need at least a partial rewrite regardless. And if you're doing that you may as well stop the insanity with all the new reallocations. if I get some time, I'll post something up.